# deploying web app to android without phonegap

Tags: java, android, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I am deploying my Sench touch 2 app to android. I am using PhoneGap to do it. It works fine but is slow. I was trying to deploy the app without PhoneGap to a embedded Webview.

I get the app running but it doesn't get past the sencha loading screen.

here my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true); // i was trying this, dont know if i need it
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

These are the permissions I have enabled

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I cant seem to figure out what I am missing. Is there something special i have to do to make this run?

Oh and LogCat dosent show any thing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not planning on calling any native code (except via Ext.Device), you could also use package your Sencha app using Sencha SDK Tools/ Sencha CMD.

Documentation at:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_android

Please note Sencha SDK Tools recently got updated to Sencha CMD, for more information and further documentation see the blogpost on the release here:
http://www.sencha.com/blog/all-new-sencha-cmd/